# Uniformly continuous of a function

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-continuity

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R} $ be  an uniformly continuous functions, how to prove that

> there are $a, b $ such that $|f(x)|\leq a|x|+b$

thanks for any suggestions

Comment: My suggestion is to search before asking.

Comment: @Dear  Live Forever, thanks your comment and suggestions, I am very   sorry